# Remove Right Column on Registration page

Tags: opencart2.x

This is link of website http://coolie.se/index.php?route=account/register
As you can see on this page there is right column. i want to remove this column. Is there anyone who can guide me? i am not expert in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set class `col-sm-9` to `col-sm-12` in tpl file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ali, here is an other link and i am unable to sort out where will be its tpl file http://coolie.se/index.php?route=account/return/add could you please kind enough to tell me tpl file name of this link?

Comment: This will be located in `template/account/return_form.tpl`.

Answer (score 1):

You should only set col-sm-9 to col-sm-12 on your HTML structure.